# Check if a List is of that type that it can ADD/Delete items?

Tags: c#, list, addition

I am having a UserControl with an ItemsSource that allows only objects, that can be enumerated (implement IEnumerable) and where I can add/delete items. How can I test the latter?

Comment: You want to test if your list can add/delete items?

Comment: yes and Icollection looks good so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `IsReadOnly` property (by casting to `IList` or `ICollection<T>`)

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the object is of type ICollection (generic) or IList (non-generic) and that their IsReadOnly property is not set to True

Comment: Why check IList if it implements anyway ICollection. Why no straight check if it is of type ICollection?

Comment: `IList` does not implement `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Check for an implementation of the ICollection-interface, instead of IEnumerable. Usually any collection class that has collection manipulation possibilities, implements this interface, or a child.